# Ionic Framework (AngularJS) Controller cannot see the declared ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

This is my HTML Cod

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" ng-controller="makeOrderController">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Tìm kiếm" ng-model="searchKeyword" ng-change="searchMenu()" >
</ion-view>
```

This is my JS code

```
....
.controller('makeOrderController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.searchMenu = function ($scope) {
        console.log($scope.searchKeyword);
    }

}]);
```

Yeah. When i type on the search textbox, the searchMenu() method is executed, but it raised an error

```
Cannot read property 'searchKeyword' of undefined
```

I have searched on SO, I tried :

- To add `$parent.` to ng-model
- Or use js statement is $`scope.model.searchKeyword`. But these code are not work :(

Please help me to help the console.log write updated keyword on user type.

Comment: You should use JSLint or JSHint to run through your code; if you use the `yeoman ionic-generator` module, it's built in.  This would catch those sort of errors.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this. I will try to explore it :D Many thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 `$scope` variables. So the inner most `$scope` is taking the preference which is undefined.

Get rid of that..

```
.controller('makeOrderController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.searchMenu = function () {
        console.log($scope.searchKeyword);
    }

}]);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9omquk97/)**